# Control font size of Spyder Python IDE on everything except the editor code

Tags: python, anaconda

How can I enlarge the font sizes of Spyder Python IDE and hereby I don't speak of the font size of the editor but the font sizes of e.g. the preferences window or the file names above the editor.

[image: output of demo script]

Comment: Did you find a fix for your problem? I'm currently facing the same issue.
For me, the weirdly scaled fonts appeared randomly after a restart, while the most annoying part is that programmed Qt applications are also wrongly displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You can scale the entire user interface by setting a custom screen resolution.

Open the Preferences dialog from the Tools menu, then under General → Appearance → Screen resolution check "Set a custom high DPI scaling" and possibly adjust the default value of 1.5 as you see fit. You will then be prompted to restart Spyder for the new settings to take effect.

This will increase the display size of all fonts, including the one used in the editor, which can however be customized separately.

Comment: Partly this solved the problem, since the editor font size is controllable by itself as you pointed out. But apart from the editor's font size, the relative proportions are completely wrong: E.g. the filenames are now readable, but the symbols are now huge. So ist still not the desired output!

Comment: To get to "screen resolution" in version 5.3.3, I had to go to:  `Tools>Preferences>Application>Interface`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today while working in a two-screen environment. The issue was solved by opening spyder in the screen where spyder looks well and then choosing `Normal` in the `Screen resolution` section of the menu in `Tools>Preferences>Application>Interface`